# Focus or Select text box on c# windows forms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a windows forms application and on startup of the application the cursor is in the wrong text box.

I've tried searching some other questions online, but nothing seems to work for me.

I've tried inputBox.Focus(); bot after the Initialize Component, I've also tried this in my input box method, and I've tried inputBox.Select(); in a few places as well. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've also seen that you can set the tab index of the text box to be zero, but unfortunately I don't understand. I can't find this option anywhere in visual studio. I figured this would be in the properties for the text box in the designer. Am I looking in the wrong place? Or should I be looking for a different solution?

Here's my code:

```
namespace Project_9
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    Bowling objectRef;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objectRef = new Bowling(10);

    }
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Jonathan Spalding\nCS1400\nProject 9");
    }
    private void inputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string text = inputBox.Text;
            if (text == "")
            {
                highScoreBox.Text = objectRef.GetHighScorePlayer() + ": " + string.Format("{0:d}", objectRef.GetHighScore());
                lowScoreBox.Text = objectRef.GetLowScorePlayer() + ": " + string.Format("{0:d}", objectRef.GetLowScore());
                averageScoreBox.Text = string.Format("{0:f2}", objectRef.GetAverageScore());
            }
            else
            {
                inputBox.Clear();
                objectRef.AddPlayer(text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the textbox. In the properties window find TabIndex (If you can not find it, sort the properties in A-Z as in the small red rectangle.

Make sure:
1. that the TabIndex is the smallest value comparing to the other controls (as in my example two comboboxes each one has a TabIndex value)
2. The TabStop value is True.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Load event

```
ActiveControl = inputBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TabIndex` property to a value bigger than 0. The control wih the least value will focus on startup.
You can then set the TabIndex on the other controls so that when you press the tab key, the next control (with higher TabIndex) will get the focus.

Answer (score 0):

In your form constructor you can use:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    inputBox.Focus();
}
```

Or

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    inputBox.Focus();
    inputBox.Select();
}
```

Comment: Thanks LP! It must have been user error on my end, or just something buggy. I tried both inputBox.Focus(); and inputBox.Select(); earlier. I tried InputBox.Select in the form constructor and it works this time, but .Focus() still doesn't work for me. Either way I got it working. I like the option to change the TabIndex so I'm using that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to set TabIndex by clicking with mouse on controls. Just go to view menu and then to TabIndexOrder menu option.
Then you can set TabIndex order just by clicking on the TabIndex represented on your form just the way you want to.
When you finish just select TabIndexOrder menu option again to exit helper.